# VLOOKUP with criterias from both row and column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013

I have a big table like this (imagine round-robin result table) where both column and row are team names that First row will be exactly like First Column

[image: Big Table]

Because the table is very big so it is hard to look up for value if I have to look for multiple values

So I'd like to create a table like this

[image: Small Table]

Let's say I want to look up the first "?" in this small table. What formula can I use to look up A2(column)xA3(row) from the big table?

I hope I made it clear enough.

Any pointers or resource I could read online would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `2&3 <> 3&2` restricts this kind of cutting... how do you know which of the 2 values you need?

Comment: Also `2&4` isn't possible at all in the small table...

Comment: @DirkReichel I hope it might look only for column A2 then row A3 from the big table. I'd assume that only 1 cell will satisfy that. Is it impossible to do that ?

Comment: Asuming you want the upper value from row 1 and the left value from column A it would look like that `=INDEX($1:$101,MATCH($A2,$A:$A,0),MATCH(B$1,$1:$1,0))` for B2 then copy left and down as you need it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break this down in two parts.

1. Get a lookup working for row values using `VLOOKUP()`. Here is an example:     `VLOOKUP($A3, BigTable!$A$2:$CW$101, 2, 0)`:

   - `$A3`: Lookup value to find. Dollar sign locks just the column so that when you drag the formula across A doesn't change
   - `BigTable!$A$2:$CW$101`: Range to find the result. Dollar sign completely locks the range so wont change
   - `2`: Column to bring back (For the time being it is always going to bring back second column)
   - `0`: Look for an exact match
2. Get a lookup working for the column values so that when the formula is copied across it automatically updates the column that it is looking for. I used `MATCH()` to find the position of the column value in BigTable. For example: `MATCH(B$1, BigTable!$B$1:$CW$1, 0)`:

   - `B$1`: Column header to lookup up the position of in the BigTable. Dollar sign locks the row so when you move it down it remains as 1
   - `BigTable!$B$1:$CW$1`: Header column to look through
   - `0`: Look for an exact match

Finally put the two pieces of the formula together and check some of the values to make sure that it is working correctly: `VLOOKUP($A2, BigTable!$A$2:$CW$101, MATCH(B$1, BigTable!$B$1:$CW$1, 0), 0)`

This would then give you one formula to copy across the whole of the SmallTable to lookup up the relevant values in the BigTable.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html

Read example 3, it is exactly like my problem.. Thank @DirkReichel for suggesting Index function, so I could know where even  to start.